# Minecraft Bedrock HTML5 UI : display inline

Tags: html, css, user-interface, minecraft

> **Info**
> This feature does not exist in the game anymore!

I’m in progress of making an in game overlay (in Minecraft Bedrock Edition) using the HTML5 UI (Build in way of creating UI with html and css deployed via a resource pack).
I want to achieve a HUD screen like look: Blocks of text with a translucent black background that adjusts itself to the size of the text like using `display: inline-block;`.

Unfortunately the html rendering engine does not support `display: inline-block`.

I assume they are using the Coherent Gameface lib:
According to their [documentation](https://coherent-labs.com/Documentation/cpp-gameface/df/d2c/css_props.html), there is pretty less support for anything!

Does anyone has some experience regarding working with Bedrock HTML5 UI, Coherent Gameface or a good idea in general to solve this with some css workaround?

Comment: Huh..? Are you trying to make an in-game overlay using Gameface with HTML/CSS? I would personally recommend Electron, as MCBE is not powered using Gameface...

Comment: No, Minecraft Bedrock has a build in way of creating custom UI with HTML using Addons ([bedrock.dev](https://bedrock.dev/docs/stable/UI)).
I had a look at the binaries and the dlls there pointed me to Gameface...

Comment: My bad - I understand you

Comment: And I assume there's no native support for custom CSS, which is why you use Gameface?

Comment: I am just providing html and css files via a resource pack and MC will render this as a UI window (I can open this via a js client script).
I can not choose which engine is used; I just assume they internally use Gameface.
My problem is that `display: inline-block;` is not supported and I’m looking for an alternative or workaround

Comment: Is `width: max-content` supported o.e.?

Comment: Sadly not ... but thank you very much for your help!
I just came up with a solution (see below)

Comment: Ah, Flexbox. Glad you were able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came up with a solution!

This is how it *LOOKED* before:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
</div>

<style>
    .container {}

    .container > div {
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

And this is my *solution*:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
</div>

<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .container > div {
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
```